# Does instantiating a DbContext From EF read the whole database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

When instantiating EntityFramework's DbContext in MVC3, does the whole database get read? When debugging, it is possible to access all of the data in the entire database by looking at the instantiated DbContext so wouldn't this imply that all the data is grabbed when the first connection is made?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No definitly not. The data is loaded, when you access the DbSet/ObjectSet properties of your DbContext.

Only the data you query for is loaded from the db and mapped to objects. For example, when you query like

```
DbContext.Table.Where(row => row.Prop1 == "Value")
```

Its translated to SQL, evaluated at the database and only the rows that match your query are returned to your app.

Answer (score 2):

No, the entire database is not read on instantiation.  The entity collections (DbSet<>) in your DbContext are lazy evaluated.  So when you're debugging and navigate into one, it's being queried then, not when the DbContext instance is instantiated.

Answer (score 1):

No, Entity Framework tries to only query the database when you need information, or you need to modify information.

The following example is my personal interpretation of what I think EF is doing behind the scenes. It's probably somewhat inaccurate, but serves a point for illustration purposes.

```
using(var db = new MyDbContext()) // 1
{
    var entities = db.MyEntities; // 2

    foreach(var entity in entities) // 3
    {
        // 4
    } // 5
} // 6
```

1. Establish connection with database
2. Get some object representing a query that says "Get me all dem entities."
3. Enumerate the object. Aka, have the context's query provider translate "get me all dem entites" to (assuming sql) "select * from MyEntity with (nolock);", and run the query returning an ADO.NET SqlDataReader, which will read the first row, map the object into an (optionally) lazy object with some metadata, so EF knows what row it's mapped to, etc, and yeild that as the "entity" variable.
4. Do something with the entity you magically received from the database without actually doing any real work (thank Entity Framework!)
5. Ask EF to move the SqlDataReader to the next row and yield another entity (aka, go back to step 3, but only if another row exists)
6. Close the connection with the database.